# "Ebenfalls" vs. "Gleichfalls"

Tags: word-choice, meaning, adverb

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *ebenfalls* und *gleichfalls*?

Können sie wechselseitig verwendet werden?

> A: Wie geht es dir?
>
> B: Sehr gut und dir?
>
> A: Gleichfalls/ Ebenfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ebenfalls" can be translated, the EVEN case.

"Gleichfalls" is more like, the EQUAL case.

Two ways of saying the same thing.

Man kann "Ebenfalls" ubersetzen wie, the EVEN case.
"Gleichfalls," ist sowie the EQUAL case.
Zwei Wege der Selbe zu sagen.

Answer (score 8):

Two variants with the same meaning. As a reaction to good wishes as "Einen schönen Tag!" you can say "Danke gleichfalls"" or "Danke ebenfalls". I prefer the first one because the pronunciation is quicker, and the second one when I want to give my reaction a bit more weight. "Ebenfalls" is a bit longer in pronunciation and so it automatically has a bit more weight.

In the situation above "Wie geht es dir?" another possible reaction could be: Ebenso, danke!
A bit stiffer, when the contact between the two persons is not very close: Ebenso, danke der Nachfrage.